# WS - Apache CXF: Response.get() in AsyncHandler returns Object instead of message

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, cxf, getresponse

I am a beginner in WS and CXF. I would like to create asynchronous client using AsyncHandler but I am not able to get response message.

I have web service class and interface generated with CXF wsdl2java like the following:

```
@WebService(...)
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TestInterface {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "update")
    public Response<?> updateAsync(
        @WebParam(partName = "MyMessage", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name = "MyMessage", targetNamespace = "...")
        javax.xml.ws.Holder myMessage
    );

    @WebMethod(operationName = "update")
    public Future<?> updateAsync(
        @WebParam(partName = "MyMessage", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name = "MyMessage", targetNamespace = "...")
        javax.xml.ws.Holder myMessage,
        @WebParam(name = "asyncHandler", targetNamespace = "")
        AsyncHandler<MyMessage> asyncHandler
    );

    @Action(input = "urn:...", output = "urn:...")
    @WebMethod
    public void update(
        @WebParam(partName = "MyMessage", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name = "MyMessage", targetNamespace = "...")
        javax.xml.ws.Holder<MyMessage> myMessage
    );
}
```

-

```
@javax.jws.WebService(...)
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface {
    public Future<?> updateAsync(javax.xml.ws.Holder MyMessage, AsyncHandler<MyMessage> asyncHandler) { 

    public Response<?> updateAsync(javax.xml.ws.Holder MyMessage) { 
       return null;
       /* not called */
    }

    public Future<?> updateAsync(javax.xml.ws.Holder MyMessage,AsyncHandler<MyMessage> asyncHandler) {
       return null;
       /* not called */
    }

    public void update(javax.xml.ws.Holder<MyMessage> MyMessage) { 
        LOG.info("Executing operation update");
        ...
    }
}
```

client class

```
public class Updater {

    @Inject
    private RequestInterface requestInterfaceClient;

    public void sendRequest(){
        Holder<MyMessage> message = createNewMessage();
        MyResponseHandler handler = new MyResponseHandler();
        RequestInterfaceClient.updateAsync(message, handler);
    }


    private Holder<MyMessage> createNewMessage() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And handler

```
public class MyResponseHandler implements AsyncHandler<MyMessage>{

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(Response<MyMessage> response) throws Exception {

            MyMessage message = response.get();
//                                       ^^^
//          returns instance of Object instead of MyMessage

    }

}
```

When `response.get()` is called `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to MyMessage` occurs.

When I debug the code, I can see that `response` contains `result` which is array of Object. There are 2 objects: 1st is instance of Object (it is returned by result.get()) and 2nd is instance of MyMessage.

My questions follow:

1. Response has not any getter with index. How can I get the second object?
2. Why response has those 2 objects and result.get() does not work?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I **prevented CXF from generating** methods with javax.xml.ws.**Holder** (I changed WSDL according to: CXF generate Holders if there is multiple outputs or the input/output message contain the same message part). 
And now it works (`response.get()` returns instance of `MyMessage`).

But still it would be nice if somebody could tell me the solution **with Holder**.

Comment: Hi! I am generating the async client as well. Any idea how to get the raw SOAP XML in the `handleResponse()` method?